# Make the delay in websphere JMS message publishing using the setLongProperty( ) method

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, websphere-7, spring-jms, jms-topic

Is websphere implementation of JMS having some property to set the delay in sending the message to JMS Queue.
Like the ones we have as follows

a) In ActiveMQ ::msg.setLongProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY, delay)
b) In JBOSS :: JBoss msg.setLongProperty(“JMS_JBOSS_SCHEDULED_DELIVERY”, delay);

Comment: Sadly no. Many times I have wished it did.

Answer (score 0):

Just released MQ 8 implements JMS 2.0 specification which has this feature. Unfortunately, its not found in the earlier versions of MQ.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q113110_.htm?lang=en

> Support for the JMS 2.0 version of the JMS standard, including deferred message delivery, shared subscriptions and asynchronous send operation

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using the WAS version as 7.0.0.31 and the provider as Default Messaging Provider with spring JMSTemplate. Is it possible to achieve this delivery delay in this combination? Please suggest me.